# The chi-square test in Python for 3 groups of data (1 variable)

Tags: python, chi-squared-test

I analyse chemical data from surface water and groundwater for a scientific paper.

My data is split into three main groups: The River, row A consisting of "x" wells, and row B consisting of "y" wells.

The main reason for this study is to check whether it is a statistically significant difference between the river, row A and Row B, in terms of given parameter content.

I have created 3 Series in Pandas, let's call them:

river, row_a ("x" wells), row_b ("y" wells)

The problem is that row_a and row_b have duplicates in the index because for "x" and "y" wells in two rows, the samples were collected on the same day, and my index is a DatetimeIndex.

I want to run a Chi-square test of independence of different variables; for this example, let's say Chlorides, but I constantly get an error "cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels". I don't know how to reset the indexes properly.

Also, there is another thing: the number of observations in the three groups is not the same, for example, 56 in the river, 77 in row A, and 44 in row B. I don't know if that is a big issue.

Comment: First, it looks like this is a question about software. These are off topic here. But maybe I am wrong. Please clarify.

Second, what kind of variable is "chlorides"?  I am guessing this is some kind of amount (maybe in parts per million or whatever). In that case, chisquare would not be right. 

Third, what is "index"?

Comment: @PeterFlom 

1) sorry, maybe I should post my question on StackOverflow... 2) You are right; chlorides is an amount - in (mg/L) (a floating point number).  "In that case, chi-square would not be right." -> why? and 3) in pandas index is an "Immutable sequence used for indexing and alignment." Something like an ordinal number in Python pandas DataFrame. And Series in Pandas is like a column in MS Excel spreadsheet...

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, you write that chlorides (and other variables) are amounts, in mg/dl.

In this case you do not want chi-square. Chi-square is about relations between categorical variables.

You want some form of regression with chlorides as the dependent variable and location (river, A, or B) as the independent variable. The usual starting point is ordinary least squares regression.